# Losing my Mind with require('path') in Windows with jnode

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

This might be a question that is already answered but none of the solutions works for me. 
trying for 3 hours.

i just want to use:

> import { dirname, basename } from 'path';  /* tried all ways of writting ./path + absolute path whatsoever */

and give it out in the console:

> console.log(dirname(__filename));

also changed the variables on my pc.

```
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Bela\Desktop\DI\Try\test.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:693:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11 {
>  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>  requireStack: []
```

}

test.js and my node_modules are in the same directory.

Thanks for help in advance  and sorry for that dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using CommonJS syntax, e.g. require('path')?

For example:

```
const { dirname, basename } = require('path');

console.log(dirname(__filename));
console.log(basename(__filename));
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm running on Windows too, this works in my case. I'm running Node.js v12.13.0. Can you do a: node --version in your command window so see what version you're running? Thanks!

Comment: PS C:\Users\Bela\Desktop\DI\Try> node --version
v13.0.1

Comment: I've tried using Node v13.0.1.. this gives the same result for me (i.e it works). How are you running the test script? Have you tried this on the command line, e.g. node test.js? It does sound very annoying. I wonder what's different about your environment that causes this issue..

Comment: if i undestand the error message correctly the code and the dir can be read tillinternal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11 {
>  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

Comment: Ah yes, very good. Same as myself! Are you in the project directory in the terminal? If not, try cding to the project directory and try running from there? I find if I'm in a different directory in the terminal from the project I get the same error as you. e.g. cd "C:\Users\Bela\Desktop\DI\Try\"

Comment: also tried to delete node_modules and re install them, dont worked

Comment: I have node node 12.13.0, running VS Code on Win10, putting @TerryLennox's code in a test.js in a folder on the desktop, and running it from the terminal with 'node test.js' works fine for me.

Comment: Also try using the "Node Exec" extension, this is really handy for VS Code, just install it, then hit F8 from your script to run it.

Comment: DELETED now everything and just have a complete new and seperated dir and the code WORKED! .. Really sorry for all the trouble.. but thanks alot for the help!! Dont know why it failed so hard all the time.

Comment: Typical Case of : "you tried to turn it off and on" , i tried everything except  shut it completly down and make a complete new one. This is my first  question so now its solved should i delete it or something like this ?

Comment: I don't think so.. it's a valid question.  You tried everything.  If it helps someone else it's worth keeping.